# How to use wait\notify Processor?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have running nifi instance 1.2.0.

I just tried to use "Wait\Notify" Processor with following reference
http://ijokarumawak.github.io/nifi/2017/02/02/nifi-notify-batch/#why-mergecontent-dont-suffice

Drag the template in canvas and i try to running it.

It shows following error in **"Wait/Notify"** processor.

`Unable to communicate with cache when processing StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=faab337f-034c-4137-a2f3-abb46f22b474,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1494485406343-1, container=default, section=1], offset=0, length=7005603],offset=5280310,name=input.csv,size=1054261] due to java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect:`

I don't know what this error says?

I am not apply any patches in 1.2.0 i just download binary file and tried it

Please stop me if anything if anything i'm missed?

And guide me to solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to create and start a DistributedMapCacheServer and DistributedMapCacheClient. The client needs to be configured with the port and host that the server is listening on.

Then the Wait and Notify processors use the DistributedMapCacheClient.

Since you were able to start the processors, you likely already have the client setup, but you don't have the server running.

Comment: @Bryan Bende -- are we supposed to loop the wait relation back to the Wait processor or auto-terminate flowfiles going to wait?

Comment: @Dan loop back to self so that it can keep checking if it should be released, once the notify happens the waiting flow file will then pass through the success relationship of the wait processor