# how to use wait notify processor for stopping invokehttp processor?

Tags: apache-nifi

I  want to stop  my invokehttp proccesor  when it has a failure (when the invokehttp processor fails, the notify processor should "notify" the wait processor about failure and it should make invokehttp processor wait or stop).

I tried  to use wait/notify processor for it but the notify processor throws an exception like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Question is possible duplicate of this
[How to use wait\notify Processor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43915412/how-to-use-wait-notify-processor)

For that solution is.,

You will need to create and start a DistributedMapCacheServer and DistributedMapCacheClient. The client needs to be configured with the port and host that the server is listening on.

Then the Wait and Notify processors use the DistributedMapCacheClient.

Since you were able to start the processors, you likely already have the client setup, but you don't have the server running.