# Using wait Processor in nifi

Tags: wait, apache-nifi

I need to use  wait processor for terminating invokehttp processor in case of failure, I  have tried  this - [How to use wait\notify Processor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43915412/how-to-use-wait-notify-processor) and added  DistributeCashMapServerService by PutDistributeMapCachProcessor (I have made host:localhost  with  port 4557  for  both DistributeMapCachclient and server service), but both of them still throws execpetion:

Here's a screenshot of the error message:
[image]

Should I change server port? Or configure it another way?

Here is my workflow:
[image]

Comment: Did you start map cache server?

Comment: I made it enable

Comment: Is it both controller services in state "enabled"?